# BufferedReader.read() cut off getting POST data in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, bufferedreader

In my servlet, I have the following code:

```
BufferedReader br = request.getReader();
char[] buff = new char[request.getContentLength()]; 
int i = br.read(buff);
```

The length of buff is 55453 but the value of i is 7618, any idea why this is getting cut off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BufferedReader seems to read only a part of the request. Try something like this:

```
char[] buff = new char[request.getContentLength()];
while (int i = br.read(buff) != -1) {
  // process buff
}
```

So 7618 seems to be the size of the buffer you get from your request object.